# Updating EF entities based on deep JSON data

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have a data structure which looks something like this: `foo 1:* bar 1:* baz`

It could look something like this when passed to the client:

```
{
    id: 1,
    bar: [{
            id: 1,
            baz: []
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            baz: [{
                id: 1
            }]
        }
    ]
}
```

In my UI, this is represented by a tree structure, where the user can update/add/remove items on all levels.

My question is, when the user has made modifications and I'm sending the altered data back to the server, how should I perform the EF database update? My initial thought was to implement dirty tracking on the client side, and make use of the dirty flag on the server in order to know what to update. Or maybe EF can be smart enough to do an incremental update itself?

Comment: EF has change tracking built in out of the box. You can try re-attaching the data back on the server and save the changes. What do the entities look like?

Comment: @Nkosi They all look pretty similar in terms of properties. A few primitive properties like "description", along with a list for the related entities as shown above.

Comment: Not actual solution for the question, but as alternative seems like NoSql approach will fit for those requirements. you will have one document per foo, where all child types included in that document. You will load documents to show in UI and on then simply update whole document.

Comment: @Fabio A good suggestion indeed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately EF provides little if no help for such scenario.

The change tracker works well in connected scenarios, but working with disconnected entities has been totally left out for the develpers using the EF. The provided context methods for manipulating entity state can handle simplified scenarios with primitive data, but does not play well with related data.

The general way to handle it is to load the existing data (icluding related) from the database, then detect and apply the add/updates/deletes yourself. But accounting for all related data (navigation property) types (one-to-many (owned), many-to-one (associated), many-to-many etc), plus the hard way to work with EF6 metadata makes the generic solution extremely hard.

The only attempt to address the issue generically AFAIK is the [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) package. Applying the modifications with that package in your scenario is simple as that:

```
using RefactorThis.GraphDiff;

IEnumerable<Foo> foos = ...;
using (var db = new YourDbContext())
{
    foreach (var foo in foos)
    {
        db.UpdateGraph(foo, fooMap =>
            fooMap.OwnedCollection(f => f.Bars, barMap =>
                barMap.OwnedCollection(b => b.Bazs)));
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

See [Introducing GraphDiff for Entity Framework Code First - Allowing automated updates of a graph of detached entities](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/) for more info about the problem and how the package is addressing the different aspects of it.

The drawback is that the package is no more supported by the author, and also there is no support for EF Core in case you decide to port from EF6 (working with disconnected entities in EF Core has some improvements, but still doesn't offer a general out of the box solution).

But implementing correctly the update manually even for specific model is a real pain. Just for comparison, the most condensed equivalent of the above `UpdateGraph` method for 3 simple entities having only primitive and collection type navigation properties will look something like this:

```
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
var fooIds = foos.Where(f => f.Id != 0).Select(f => f.Id).ToList();
var oldFoos = db.Foos
    .Where(f => fooIds.Contains(f.Id))
    .Include(f => f.Bars.Select(b => b.Bazs))
    .ToDictionary(f => f.Id);
foreach (var foo in foos)
{
    Foo dbFoo;
    if (!oldFoos.TryGetValue(foo.Id, out dbFoo))
    {
        dbFoo = db.Foos.Create();
        dbFoo.Bars = new List<Bar>();
        db.Foos.Add(dbFoo);
    }
    db.Entry(dbFoo).CurrentValues.SetValues(foo);
    var oldBars = dbFoo.Bars.ToDictionary(b => b.Id);
    foreach (var bar in foo.Bars)
    {
        Bar dbBar;
        if (!oldBars.TryGetValue(bar.Id, out dbBar))
        {
            dbBar = db.Bars.Create();
            dbBar.Bazs = new List<Baz>();
            db.Bars.Add(dbBar);
            dbFoo.Bars.Add(dbBar);
        }
        else
        {
            oldBars.Remove(bar.Id);
        }
        db.Entry(dbBar).CurrentValues.SetValues(bar);
        var oldBazs = dbBar.Bazs.ToDictionary(b => b.Id);
        foreach (var baz in bar.Bazs)
        {
            Baz dbBaz;
            if (!oldBazs.TryGetValue(baz.Id, out dbBaz))
            {
                dbBaz = db.Bazs.Create();
                db.Bazs.Add(dbBaz);
                dbBar.Bazs.Add(dbBaz);
            }
            else
            {
                oldBazs.Remove(baz.Id);
            }
            db.Entry(dbBaz).CurrentValues.SetValues(baz);
        }
        db.Bazs.RemoveRange(oldBazs.Values);
    }
    db.Bars.RemoveRange(oldBars.Values);
}
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, at least I know I'm not reinventing the wheel now :)

Comment: Yeah, and you are not alone. Unfortunately this is the reality with EF.

Comment: Right now I'm thinking of handling each entity type in a separate list, flagging the items dirty, added or removed. Any thoughts on that approach?

Comment: Btw, do you know if graphdiff would work in EF db first?

Comment: I can't say hundred percent (honestly I never used db first), but I don't see any reason why it shouldn't. After all, once the model is built (in one or another way), the metadata and db context services are one and the same.

Comment: What about the other question, I guess you mean the idea of client side tracking? I think it's viable approach, although you still will need to correctly attach the data to the context and work with state to let EF do updates/removes (add is easy). Anyway, if you are going to that direction, you may find helpful the [Data Points - Handling the State of Disconnected Entities in EF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694083.aspx) post by Julie Lerman.

Comment: Right, my thought was to use a state property on the client side which I can translate to EF's once they reach the server.

Comment: Hi again, if you have time, could you please explain how I can make GraphDiff remove root objects - `foo` - too?

Comment: Never mind, think I found the answer https://github.com/zzzprojects/GraphDiff/issues/94 Thanks anyway!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, I wasn't around for a while. But glad that you've found what you need meanwhile :)